# How to make the users of a Custom Group see the folders and files inside a folder, and not be able to open the files?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016, file-permissions

I need to give permissions to a `Custom Group` in `Active Directory` in such a way that the `users` of that group are able to see the folders and files that are present in the folder, but are not able to open the files. How can I do that?

I initially gave `List folder contents` permission, but that was only displaying the folders and not the files. On the other hand, when I give `List folder contents` permission for 'This folder, subfolders, and files`from under`Advanced Security Settings >> Permission Entry`, I see that the permission is changed to`Read and Execute`.

So, in a nut-shell, I need the user to be able to see the list of folders and files that are there in the folder to which I give this permission to, and not have any kind of `read` permission.

Comment: Shot in the dark, how about allowing that, then denying read permission?

Comment: I have just added `List folder options` from `Security` tab of `Folder Properties`. With this, the user is able to see the list of only the folders and none of its contents. But, @WaleedHamra as you suggested, on removing `Read` permission from `Special Permissions` window, all the other permissions are also going away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error in your method is you're applying it to "This folder, subfolders, and files". Instead, give read & execute, read, traverse on "This folder and subfolders". They will have access to traverse folders, but can't read the contents of any file, unless some other group is giving them read permissions on the files.

Comment: I can't still see the files in the list.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the security permission involved?